# Major arcs in the proof that every odd number is the sum of at most 5 primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

In his proof that all odd numbers greater than 1 are the sum of at most 5 primes, Terence Tao uses one large major arc around 0 rather than small ones around the rationals, which I am more accustomed to seeing. What are the advantages of using such a major arc?

Here is the paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.6656.pdf